# PyQt 4 : setupUi() unbound method error

Tags: python, eclipse, pyqt4

I am starting to learn to use PyQt4. I've got a simple gui window I want to show (nothing fancy).

Here's the code for that :

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from test import Ui_MainWindow

class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self, parent=None):
       QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
       self.ui = Ui_MainWindow
       self.ui.setupUi(self)          

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But eclipse is giving me following error:

```
TypeError: unbound method setupUi() must be called with Ui_MainWindow instance
as first argument (got MyForm instance instead)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well self certainly points to the current instance of the class where it is called, in your case it really points to MyForm which subclassed QtGui.QMainWindow, while your setupUi method requires an instance of Ui_MainWindow

Comment: So, are you seeing an error ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should inherit `Ui_MainWindow`:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from test import Ui_MainWindow

class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
   def __init__(self, parent=None):
       QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
       self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Or you can create an `Ui_MainWindow` instance:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from test import Ui_MainWindow

class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self, parent=None):
       QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
       self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()    #note: instance, not the class
       self.ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Bakuriu said, you want

```
self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
```

, not

```
self.ui = Ui_MainWindow
```

. You are currently assigning the class itself to self.ui, not creating an instance of the class. Therefore, the call is not "bound" to a member, but unbound (tries to operate on the whole class).